# JavaScript String.replace callback to check at every other line

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am trying to use the `string.replace` function with a callback so that, based on the number, I can replace characters at alternating indexes. The string is a "board", simply a string of hashtags that have to be replaced with spaces.

Ex. board of size 8 (8x8):

```
########
########
########
########
########
########
########
########
```

Expected output:

```
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # #
```

Ex. board of size 7 (7x7):

```
#######
#######
#######
#######
#######
#######
#######
```

Expected output:

```
 # # # 
# # # #
 # # # 
# # # #
 # # # 
# # # #
 # # #
```

My current logic for my replace callback is this:

```
board.replace(/#/g, (matched, index, original) => {
    if (index % 2 === 0) {
       return " ";
    } else {
       return matched;
    }
});
```

This current logic covers the case of an even-sized board (ex. 8) but in the case of an odd number, I'd like to alternate the indexes I replace for the empty space with.

Currently, when passed an odd-numbered board it returns this:

```
 # # # 
 # # # 
 # # # 
 # # # 
 # # # 
 # # # 
 # # #
```

Is there some sort of regex that would allow me to check for alternating lines? Or is this even possible at all within the callback? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you could track the index yourself and ignore the replace function index.

```js
const board = `#######
#######
#######
#######
#######
#######
#######`;

// First way
let i = 0;
const result = board.replace(/#/g, () => i++ % 2 === 0 ? ' ' : '#');
console.log(result);


// Fancy
function countCalls(fn) {
  let calls = 0;
  return (...args) => fn(calls++, ...args);
}

const result2 = board.replace(/#/g, countCalls(i => i % 2 === 0 ? ' ' : '#'));
console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to take into account the line number. I'd split into lines, then test `index + lineNum % 2 === 0`.

```js
const board = `#######
#######
#######
#######
#######
#######
#######`;

const result = board.split('\n').map((line, lineNum) => {
  return line.replace(/#/g,
      (char, index) => (index + lineNum) % 2 === 0 ? ' ' : '#'
    );
}).join('\n');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew I had to take the line number into account somehow, just wasn't sure if I was able to use some sort of regex magic for it.

Answer (score 1):

To do this with `.replace` *alone*, without anything else, would be a bit tricky. Consider matching lines instead, and using another `.replace` which checks (and toggles) a flag indicating whether the first element should be removed or not:

```js
const alternate = (board) => {
  let hashFirst = false;
  const result = board.replace(
    /.+/g,
    (line) => {
      const res = line.replace(
        /#/g,
        (_, index) => index % 2 === (hashFirst ? 1 : 0) ? ' ' : '#'
      )
      hashFirst = !hashFirst;
      return res;
    }
  );
  console.log(result);
}

alternate(`#######
#######
#######
#######
#######
#######
#######`);
alternate(`#####
#####
#####
#####
#####`);
alternate(`####
####
####
####`);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I had a feeling one replace wasnt going to do it but this akes much more sense.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the easiest way would be to split the input and then run a similar function to yours but adding `i` and `j` indexes:

```js
const board1 = `#######
#######
#######
#######
#######
#######
#######`;

const board2 = `########
########
########
########
########
########
########
########`;

function splitBoard(board) {
  return board
    .split('\n')
    .reduce((splitted, hashesArray, i) => 
      `${splitted}\n${hashesArray.replace(/#/g, (_, j) => (i + j) % 2 ? '#' : ' ')}`
    , '')
}

console.log(splitBoard(board1))
console.log(splitBoard(board2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could execute `String#replace` seperately on each line instead of directly the whole board.

Then check the index of the current line index and the current column index to know what is the next character to be inserted.

```js
const board = `#####
#####
#####
#####
#####`;

let lines = board.split(/\n/),
  finalBoard = '';

for (let lineIndex in lines) {
  const line = lines[lineIndex];
  
  line.replace(/#/g, (match, charIndex) => {
    const nextIsEmpty = (charIndex % 2 + lineIndex % 2) !== 1;
  
    if (nextIsEmpty)
      finalBoard += ' ';
    else
      finalBoard += '#';
  });
  
  finalBoard += '\n';
}

console.log(finalBoard);
```